# Block dates in windows apps

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, datepicker

I am working with DatePicker in Windows apps(tablet desktop). I want to block some date on the datePicker so that user can not select them. I looked up on the google, msdn but could not find much information.

I got suggestions of using 'DisplayDateStart', 'DisplaydateEnd'but when i use them i get errors - 'DatePicker does not contain a definition for DisplayDateStart and no extension method DisplaydateStart accepting a first argument of type DatePicker could be found'.

Please share your thoughts on how to get it working

XAML:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spDatePicker">

</StackPanel>
```

XAML.cs

```
        DatePicker datePickerWithBlackoutDates = new DatePicker();            

        datePickerWithBlackoutDates.DisplayDateStart = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1);
        datePickerWithBlackoutDates.DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(2009, 8, 31);
        datePickerWithBlackoutDates.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2009, 8, 10);

        datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
            new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 1), new DateTime(2009, 8, 2)));
        datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
            new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 8), new DateTime(2009, 8, 9)));
        datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
            new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 15), new DateTime(2009, 8, 16)));
        datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
            new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 22), new DateTime(2009, 8, 23)));
        datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
            new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 29), new DateTime(2009, 8, 30)));

        datePickerWithBlackoutDates.DateValidationError +=
            new EventHandler<DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs>(DatePicker_DateValidationError);

        // root is a Panel that is defined elsewhere.
        spDatePicker.Children.Add(datePickerWithBlackoutDates);
```

Your help much appreciated.
Thanks
Rao

Answer (score 0):

Use the calendar date picker, you are looking at wpf controls which doesn't have full feature parity with windows store api. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.mindate.aspx

As per  [Setting Mindate and MaxDate for Datepicker Control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32577168/371637)

```
CalendarDatePicker cdp=new CalendarDatePicker();
cdp.MinYear=DateTime.Now();
cdp.MaxYear=DateTime.AddYears(3)
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this but it says 'CalendarDatePicker' can not be found

Comment: I just generated a new store project, added a button and added that first line into it, worked fine. The MinYear isn't present and you need MinDate instead (form the url I posted above). Ensure at the top of your file you have the imports for:  using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

Comment: ugh.. sorry I just realized I read this as Windows Store, you are doing _desktop_ to clarify, right? Not store? From a desktop WPF app standpoint your code compiled fine on my system with a new WPF app. Specificalyl - which app type are you creating?

Comment: Hi Adam, I created a universal application App (Windows 8.1). i am not sure if that is WPF. i am pretty new to windows development

Comment: Sorry I think I mentioned Store apps, but it is windows app.

Comment: email me on over at adamt at Microsoft, want to get more details here.