# How to set Max Date / Min Date to WinPhone DatePicker

Tags: windows-phone-8, datepicker, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I am developing WinPhone apps.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker" MinYear="2016" MaxYear="2017"/>
```

The code is not working.

I am able to choose previous years and I am able to choose 2015, 2018, etc. If possible, I would like to disable the months and days in DatePicker itself.

In short, I would like to set minimum and maximum allowed date for calendar so that unwanted dates are disabled in the calendar.

Comment: Hi Rajan! Are you using Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: No... I am using Xamarin Native

Comment: Thanks Rajan. Xamarin Native only applies to iOS and Android. Developing a WinPhone app without using Xamarin.Forms does not involve Mono or the Xamarin technology stack. One answer below was already given using Xamarin.Forms, so I’ve removed “Xamarin” from your question to help get you better answers.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick - I am developing winphone and uwp using Xamarin Native as well.

Comment: Native WinPhone and UWP development doesn’t use Mono or the Xamarin stack

Comment: @BrandonMinnick - so its directly uses its own windows SDK you mean to say ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePicker#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_DatePicker_MinYear), XAML parser doesn't have a conversion logic for converting strings to dates as `DateTimeOffset` objects, so `MinYear` and `MaxYear` property couldn't be set as a XAML attribute string. There are to options to set these properties:

1. To do it in the C# code. An example could be found [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-DatePicker-and-94ef5709/sourcecode?fileId=86649&pathId=93567914).
2. To provide relevant properties in your view model class (or another object in the data context) and use bindings to propagate values to the `DatePicker` control.

View model class:

```
public DateTimeOffset MinYear
{
    get { return new DateTime(2016, 1, 1); }
}

public DateTimeOffset MaxYear
{
    get { return new DateTime(2017, 12, 31); }
}
```

XAML layout:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker" MinYear="{Binding MinYear}" MaxYear="{Binding MaxYear}" />
```

Comment: I would like to set minimum and maximum day as well ! basically I want to set maximum and minimum date rather than year

Comment: @RajanM You cannot do it with `DatePicker`. Check a workaround at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32577387/2595805

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Xamarin.Forms then

```xml
<StackLayout>
  <DatePicker VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}">
     <DatePicker.Format>yyyy-MM-dd</DatePicker.Format>
     <DatePicker.MinimumDate>
        <sys:DateTime x:FactoryMethod="Parse">
           <x:Arguments>
              <x:String>Jan 1 2000</x:String>
           </x:Arguments>
        </sys:DateTime>
     </DatePicker.MinimumDate>
     <DatePicker.MaximumDate>
        <sys:DateTime x:FactoryMethod="Parse">
           <x:Arguments>
              <x:String>Dec 31 2050</x:String>
           </x:Arguments>
        </sys:DateTime>
     </DatePicker.MaximumDate>
  </DatePicker>
```

Retrieved from https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker/

If you want to just have years, then use a normal picker and give it a list of years in your accepted range. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/

Comment: Thanks Joagwa! The question is asking about a Native WinPhone app, not Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I would still do the above, regarding to using a standard picker, or flyoutpicker/flyout if a UWP app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout
And just have a list of years choosable.

Comment: @Joagwa - Can the Xaml be used in win phone ? I'm confused because I am doing xamarin Native development

Comment: I assume by "Xamarin Native" you mean you are doing a bespoke ui using Xamarin for iOS and Android, and reusing your VM for a bespoke WP app. The XAML will be different, but look at the link for the flyout which is a UWP control, which you can use with a listview to allow the user to select a year.

Comment: @Joagwa - unfortunately I have to do it for day and month as well

Answer (score 1):

In Winphone 8.1 there is *no way to set 
minimum and maximum dates* but as [eugene-berdnikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2595805/eugene-berdnikov) suggested in the above post you can set *MinYear* and *MaxYear* for the month and day you'll have to handle through code validation.

But *UWP(Universal Windows Platform)* has a [CalendarDatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CalendarDatePicker) using which you can set *MinDate* and *MaxDate* property

if you want to support windows 10 and future releases you may start migrating to UWP(Universal Windows Platform)

Here is a migration [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-porting-to-a-uwp-project)

Its as easy as Creating a New UWP project and copying existing files and rewrite some code thats all.

*ViewModel Class*

```
public DateTimeOffset MinDate
{
    get { return new DateTime(2016, 1, 1); }
}

public DateTimeOffset MaxDate
{
    get { return new DateTime(2017, 12, 31); }
}
```

*XAML Layout*

```
<CalendarDatePicker MinDate="{Binding MinDate}" MaxDate="{Binding MaxDate}"/>
```

*Code behind*

```
CalendarDatePicker calObj=new CalendarDatePicker();

DateTime minDate =  new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
minDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(minDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTimeOffset min_Date = minDate;

DateTime maxDate =  new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
maxDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(maxDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTimeOffset max_Date = maxDate;

calObj.MinDate=min_Date;
calObj.MaxDate=max_Date;
```

Kindly know that UWP also supports *DatePicker* which is part of windows phone 8.1

My suggestion is in winphone 8.1 use DatePicker and Windows 10 use CalendarDatePicker

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/date-and-time) is list of Date and Time controls available in UWP

Most of the windows phone 8.1 devices has got 10 update as well so you may see lots of people moving towards 10

Comment: any third party controls to do that in windows 8.1 ?

Comment: CalendarDatePicker is useful one but its not available in 8.1... good to know date picker is available for 10 too