# How to set a maximum date on a Xaml page and make the dates according to disabled

Tags: c, xaml, xamarin, datetimepicker

Good morning Everyone

I cannot fix a maximum date on a calendar and make "disabled" the dates which arrive after this date.
I found this ->

[Setting Mindate and MaxDate for Datepicker Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577168/setting-mindate-and-maxdate-for-datepicker-control)

But it doesn't help me.
[For example, I would like to have January 22 grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZBOA.png)

```
<DatePicker x:Name="PickerDate" 
                                    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    Date="{Binding PickerDate.Date, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    Format="dd/MM/yy"
                                    DateSelected="OnDateSelected" 
                                    IsVisible="False"
                                    iOSSpecific:Picker.UpdateMode="WhenFinished"
                                    HeightRequest="80"
                                    MaximumDate="{Binding PickerDate.MaximumDate}"
                                    />
```

Thanks for time and help (sorry for my english)

```
 PickerDate = new DatePicker();

 PickerDate.Date = DateTime.Today;

 PickerDate.MaximumDate= PickerDate.Date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PickerDate = new DatePicker();
```

Remove the line

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the `MaximumDate` binding does not bind correctly.

If you just hard code the MaximumDate like `MaximumDate="01/24/2021"`, it works as except.

Here is an example I test:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <DatePicker x:Name="PickerDate" 
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                Date="01/21/2021" 
                                Format="dd/MM/yy"
                                HeightRequest="80"
                                MaximumDate="01/24/2021"
                                />
</StackLayout>
```

And the result:

[image]

And you do not need to initialize the DataPicker again if you already wrote it in Xaml, remove the `PickerDate = new DatePicker();`.