How to set a max and min date of a `DatePicker` as it has only `MinYear` and `MaxYear`
The MaxYear and MinYear properties take a DateTimeOffset but it ignores the month and day components. I guess that's why the property was named with "Year".
Seems a very strange design decision.
Update
I'm using a DatePicker together with a TimePicker:

So using a CalendarDatePicker doesn't look so neat.

Only CalendarDatePicker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker has that.

Refer to the thread:https://stackoverflow.com/a/32577387
If you want to set MinDate and MaxDate properties, you should use CalendarDatePicker

I'm letting the user choose both date and time. Won't it look odd with a CalendarDatePicker and a TimePicker since they look different?

If you want to set MinDate and MaxDate properties, you could only use CalendarDatePicker. If you're looking for a neat look, I recommend that you could try to create a custom control.
